# Java Jsyn set input, process and get output of filter

Tags: java, audio, filter, process, jsyn

I am writing a VST-Plugin with the JVSTWrapper.
I need a filter, but I don't want to write it by myself, so I decided to use the Lowpassfilter from Jsyn.
But I don't want to do everything with Jsyn, just the filter. My question is: Is there a way to write native float[] audio data into the input of the filter, call a function which processes the data through, and get the output again as float[] audio data?

Answer (score 0):

JSyn was designed to work as a flowgraph where data flows through input and output ports. I haven't tried this but you might get something like this to work.

```
double[] inputs = filter.input.getValues();
// TODO: write data to inputs array
filter.generate(0, inputs.length());

double[] outputs = output.getValues();
// TODO: read result from the outputs array
```